# I have a question regarding promise, In Promises the flow is then() and finally() but here I am getting O/P of finally first later then()

Tags: web3js, blockchain

```js
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:8545")); // connecting to Ganache
let bal = web3.eth.getBalance("0xF658C5F7DceEd9d3783dEE9900045ACB67c9214c"); // fetching the balance

bal
.then((bal)=>(console.log(Web3.utils.fromWei(bal,"ether")))) // converting from wei to ether 
.finally(console.log("done and dusted succesfully"))

// .then((bal)=>console.log(bal)) displaying the value or the result

web3.eth.sendTransaction(
    {
        from:"0xF658C5F7DceEd9d3783dEE9900045ACB67c9214c",
        to:"0x715A917000A77BBc9c4BDB9F4c16c85c9b515BDA", 
        value:web3.utils.toWei("1","ether")
    }
)
```

```
//OUTPUT

done and dusted succesfully
(node:12601) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
73.949423
```

Comment: This is fundamentally a question about JavaScript, which would be better asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are evaluating the expression in `finally` right away. You need to pass a function instead.

You are doing something like:

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
}).then((a) => console.log("inside then a: ", a))
.finally(console.log("in finally"))
```

When in really you should do:

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
}).then((a) => console.log("inside then a: ", a))
.finally(() => console.log("in finally"))
```

Notice the `() => console.log("in finally")` instead of simply `console.log("in finally")`.

So, in simple terms, pass a function to the `then`, `catch` and `finally` instead of an expression or something like that.